# SQL - how to get 0 in SQL as counting result?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, null

I created SQL query which should count the number of e-mails sent after 20.12.2022 for each user_id from ACTIONQUEUE table. My query counts everything correctly for all users, but it doesn't returns 0 in the table for the users with ID 3 and 4, who haven't received any e-mails after 20.12.2022. How should I modify my query to fill in the RESULT table with 0 for these users?

ACTIONQUEUE table:

```
| User_ID  | Sent_date  |
| -------- | --------   |
| 2        | 31.12.2022 |
| 3        | 17.01.2023 |
| 2        | 01.01.2023 |
| 1        | 02.01.2023 |
| 5        | 31.12.2022 |
| 5        | 03.01.2023 |
| 4        | 15.12.2022 |
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT USER_ID, COUNT (SENT_DATE)
FROM ACTIONQUEUE
WHERE SENT_DATE > 20.12.2022
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

My result:

```
| User_ID | Count(Sent_date) |
| ------- | ---------------- |
| 1       | 1                |
| 2       | 2                |
| 5       | 2                |
```

Expected result:

```
| User_ID | Count(Sent_date) |
| ------- | ---------------- |
| 1       | 1                |
| 2       | 2                |
| 3       | 0                |
| 4       | 0                |
| 5       | 2                |
```

Comment: if there is no record for user_id=4 in the table how can db find out that you need it

Comment: You need to get the UserId values to count, probably from your Users table or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `ACTIONQUEUE` table already have all users which you want to report, then one solution here would be to count the condition in the current `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT USER_ID, SUM(SENT_DATE > '2022-12-20') AS cnt
FROM ACTIONQUEUE
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand the answer provided by *@Tim Biegeleisen*, your query is working only with records above 2022-12-20 so the records under that date won't exist in your query and won't be counted by `count` or be shown by the `user_id`

When you use what he suggested, the query will return a column for the user_ids and a column for the condition `SENT_DATE > '2022-12-20'`. If the condition is true it will return "1" and if it's false it will return "0" for each entry in the table ACTIONQUEUE. After that you can `SUM` the *zeros* and *ones* grouping by user_id.